# How to change url after successful api call in saga

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-saga

Use case:

After a user subscribes I want to navigate to another page, that informs the user to verify their email.

```
  try {
    const request = yield call(subcribe, action.payload.data)
    yield put({ type: SUBSCRIBE_SUCCESS, payload: request.data })
    yield put(showNotification(NOTIFICATION_SUCCESS, 'Please check your email.'))
  } catch(e) {
    ...
  }
```

is there a way to navigate to the success page i.e `/subscribe-success` once I have received a successful response from the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you get a success response from your server, you should change your redux state to something like subsribeSuccess : true. So that you have the chance to check this state in your component's componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) and do browserHistory.push('subscribe-success').

Here is an example :

Assuming you have changed your redux state to {...state, subscribeSuccess : true} from reducer, when your reducer gets SUBSCRIBE_SUCCESS action type.

On your react component :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(myConnectedReduxState.subscribeSuccess){
    browserHistory.push('subscribe-success');
  }
}
```

So as far as I understood, your problem is not related to saga. You can implement this logic anywhere in your react-redux projects.

Comment: yes you're correct it wasn't specific to saga. thank you for your response it allowed me to consider using the push function within the react-router i.e `import { push } from 'react-router-redux'` and then change the location like so `yield put(push('subscribe-success'))`. I also implemented your suggested logic in the component to render a different view.  thanks again!